# What is this code doing - Splitting a string and creating a GUID

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to understand a piece of source code, and I do not currently have access to build/debug the code. Can someone assist in explaining what the intent of the below code is?

The mixture of splitting the string, and using the split string to create a GUID is throwing me for a trip.

```
string titleOfItem = "valuePassedAsParameter";    
Guid itemId = new Guid(titleOfItem.Split(new string[] { "Approve ", "Decline "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]);
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile.

Comment: I couldn't copy it from the VM I'm working on so I had to free-form type it. Give me one sec...

Comment: No offence but I am surprised, with such a reputation score, was it really so difficult to understand what those 2 lines are doing?!

Comment: @dotnetkid yea, the .Split method kind of threw me off. I didn't write this code, and I guess I'm used to much cleaner code than this. I had a good feeling on what it was doing, but it just seemed so odd; I thought I'd get a second opinion.

Comment: [Using a Regex](https://xkcd.com/208/) would make it much clearer how the input is supposed to be formed, and provide better validation also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have a string that looks like

```
"Something Approve {18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}"
```

then

```
"Something Approve {18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}".Split(new string[] { "Approve ", "Decline " },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

will produce the string array

```
["Something "], ["{18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}"]
```

then the [1] will take the second item (the stringized GUID)

```
new Guid("{18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}")
```

will produce a guid whose parts are according the the parsed guid string

Comment: Sorry if I'm nitpicking and not commenting immediately (I didn't have rep to comment)

the code that you've written :
"Approve {18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}".Split(new string[] { "Approve ", "Decline " },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

will produce an array looking like [" "], ["{18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}"]

but RemoveEmptyEntries will get rid of the empty string so the result will be only one element ["{18e4ccaf-e2d7-476f-93b2-251dea286f65}"]

Answer (score 2):

I assume the "valuePassedAsParameter" is something containing a GUID inside but represented as string.

So what the code does is splitting this string by two keywords ("Approve" and "Decline") and removing the empty values, meaning that at the end of the split you get an array of all strings that are before or after these keywords themselves and all empty strings are not included in the array.

So after that the code takes the [1] index which is the second element in the array and is creating a GUID from it (that's why I'm assuming there's a GUID in you string)